# Getting error when trying to set min width using ButtonTheme

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart-2

I am trying to set minWidth in ButtonTheme. I am getting following error:

```
Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
compiler message:     minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40,
```

For reference I am sharing code here:

```
final resetButton = ButtonTheme(
    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-40,
    height: 50.0,
    child: new RaisedButton(
        color: blueColor,
        onPressed: (){
//          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Home.tag);
        },
        child: Text('Log In',
          style: styleLoginButton,
        ),
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `MediaQuery.of(context)` when there is no context. Either pass `context` when you call this code from `build(BuildContext context) { ... }` or move the code to `build() { ... }`